# How to pass in an 'id' when clicking on a 'View Full Profile' link

Tags: php, sql

I am working on some functionality where having performed an initial search, a subset of profile details are being displayed.  This works fine.

There is then a link called 'View Full Profile' which if clicked should return the entire profile.

I have got this working with a hardcoded id, but am not sure how to pass in the id of the profile from the subset of information?

I don't actually know if that value (the id of the profile) is currently available for me to acccess so that I can pass it in if that makes sense?

In the subset of profile details I have included a hidden field which does contain the id I would like to pass in but I'm not sure if this can be used?

The relevant code is posted below.

SUBSET-PROFILE.HTML.PHP

```
    <div id="Profile" class="Profile"  >

    <h1 class="margin-top">Search Results</h1>

    <?php if (isset($results)): ?>

    <?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>

    <ol class="coach-display">
    <li class="left image">
      <img src="<?php if (!empty($result['filename'])) echo('?action=view&id=' . $result['id']); else echo "/img/profile_coming_soon.jpg" ?>" width="80" height="80" />
      </li>
    <li class="listleft">First Name:</li>
    <li><?php htmlout($result['firstname']); ?></li>

    <li class="listleft">Last Name:</li>
    <li><?php htmlout($result['lastname']); ?></li>

    <li class="listleft">Constituency:</li>
    <li><?php htmlout($result['constituency']); ?></li>

    <li class="listleft">Qualifications:</li>
    <li><?php htmlout($result['qualifications']); ?></li>

    </ol>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($result['id']); ?>">

    <a href="?more">View full profile</a>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

INDEX.PHP

```
    if (isset($_GET['more']))
    {
        try
        {

        $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, area, county, constituency, qualifications, bio, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday,
                filename, mimetype
                FROM pt
                WHERE id = 6";
        $s = $pdo->query($sql);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = 'Error fetching pt details.' . $e->getMessage();;
            include 'profiles.html.php';
            exit();
        }
```

You can see in INDEX.PHP where I have hard coded the value to 6.  This is the value that I need to be dynamic dependent on which profile subset was previously being viewed.

Thanks for your time and help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<a href="?more">View full profile</a>
```

to

```
<a href="?more&id=<?php htmlout($result['id']); ?>">View full profile</a>
```

Now you can get id value using `$_GET['id']`..

Comment: Thanks, for this, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, but most simple is probably passing the id in the url:

```
<a href="?more&id=<?php htmlout($result['id']); ?>">View full profile</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for help with this, looks like you were just pipped to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the ID will come from GET param as well.

```
if (isset($_GET['more']))
    {
        try
        {

        $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, area, county, constituency, qualifications, bio, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday,
                filename, mimetype
                FROM pt
                WHERE id = ?";
        $sth = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
        $sth->execute(array( $_GET['id'] ));
        $s= $sth->fetchAll();
        }
```

Noticed I used different PDO functions. You need variable binding to avoid SQL injections (or a good filtering).

More details at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

ps. try to abstract your input. Never use $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE etc directly in your logic.